# Jest how to wait for mock to be called based on simulate event

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I have a test like this which fails because mock is not called, the problem is that the mock is called but before test finished.

```
test('should submit if proper values', () => {
  const spy = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
    data: {
      authenticateUser: {
        id: 123,
        token: 'lol'
      }
    }
  });
  mountedWrapper.setProps({
    loginMutation: spy
  });
  expect(spy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  email.simulate('change', {
    target: { name: 'username', value: 'email@test.com' }
  });
  password.simulate('change', {
    target: { name: 'password', value: 'secret' }
  });
  form.simulate('submit');
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

However I can get the test to pass if I add the following setTimeout

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }, 0);
```

However I am looking for a nicer approach to the above problem. Any solutions out there without setTimeout ?

Comment: Can you some more code snippets as to what is mounted Wrapper, where is email coming from etc etc?

Comment: Sorry, but your code still a bit unlear. What happens when `submit` is simulated on `form`. Is `loginMutation` called directly, or it's called after some chanin of actions? Can you please add snippets to make this clear?

Comment: Is it passing or a false-positive? I mean, if you add a `expect(true).toBe(false)` in your `setTimeout`, is it still passing?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're trying to test some asynchronous code. Did you read [this](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html)? Under `callbacks` section you can find:

> By default, Jest tests complete once they reach the end of their execution. That means this test will not work as intended:

```js
// Don't do this!
test('the data is peanut butter', () => {
  function callback(data) {
    expect(data).toBe('peanut butter');
  }

  fetchData(callback);
});
```

> The problem is that the test will complete as soon as fetchData completes, before ever calling the callback.
>   There is an alternate form of test that fixes this. Instead of putting the test in a function with an empty argument, use a single argument called done. Jest will wait until the done callback is called before finishing the test.

```js
test('the data is peanut butter', done => {
  function callback(data) {
    expect(data).toBe('peanut butter');
    done();
  }

  fetchData(callback);
});
```

> If done() is never called, the test will fail, which is what you want to happen.

That's example for `callback`, but you can also use [promises](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html#promises), [.resolves/.rejects](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html#resolves-rejects), and [async/await](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html#async-await).